# Why am I getting errors with this JavaScript line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app

I'm using a TypeScript-generated JavaScript file in my `create-react-app`. The TypeScript code contains the following line:

```
[this.variable1, this.variable2] = Helper.loadData();
```

This gets compiled to the JavaScript:

```
var _a;
_a = __read(mymodule.Helper.loadData(), 2), this.variable1 = _a[0], this.variable2 = _a[1];
```

Running this in `create-react-app`, I get a compilation error:

> Line 514:13:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

When I refactor the generated JavaScript manually to the following fragment, everything runs fine:

```
var _a;
_a = __read(mymodule.Helper.loadData(), 2);
this.variable1 = _a[0];
this.variable2 = _a[1];
```

Why does the line in question generate that error? Is this a bug in TypeScript?

Comment: That's a linting error, not a compilation error. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions

Comment: maybe you can try `;[this.variable1, this.variable2] = Helper.loadData();`

Comment: LInting rules are made to serve you and your team. If it doesn't help, consider turning it off?

Comment: Also linting trans-piled code seems odd..

Comment: Why is the linter complaining about transpiled code anyway?

Comment: So the verdict is that it **is** a TypeScript bug? What version of the transpiler are you using OP?

Comment: @Pointy it's TypeScript 3.7.4

Comment: @Pointy @VLAZ Is it really a bug? The variable `_a` is used only for the destructuring of the array. Its value does not matter after this line.

Comment: @cheesussaysstopfiringmods well you're right that it doesn't hurt anything, but it's kind-of ugly.

Comment: @Pointy well, it's transpiled code.. so the actual "error" was that `create-react-app` treats linting warnings as errors instead of as warnings.